# twitter api max app per developer account

Tags: twitter, limit, rate

I'm using the twitter api to get data on many twitter accounts, because of the rate limit and since i can't ask the owners of all those twitter accounts to authenticate, i've to create several applications on my developer account
(note that i'm already queuing and combining requests, i've used all best practices).

My question, what's the maximum number of applications allowed per developer account? i didn't manage to get this answer anywhere on the web nor on the twitter documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should NOT make more than one Application for one application.

You need to handle data logically. Cache the data you are requesting so you can limit the number of requests to twitter's API.

How to limit requests: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#5823

Here are some docs:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

and https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/8126

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned in 24 July 2018 twitter announcement, The limit is 10 apps per dev account.

> We’re also limiting the default number of apps you may have registered
>   by a single developer account to 10. Developers who need to register
>   more than 10 apps — for instance, to enable client-specific products
>   which require distinct apps —  can request permission using the API
>   Policy support form. If you already have more than 10 apps registered,
>   you can continue to use them as long as they comply with our rules but
>   you won’t be able to register new apps until you either request
>   permission for additional apps or delete unused ones.

https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/new-developer-requirements-to-protect-our-platform.html

Also, note that you can only create 3 new apps in a 24 hour period.