# how many apps can I build with one twitter account

Tags: api, twitter

I'm using Twitter API to crawl some data.
I'm just wondering how many apps I can build with one account to let me bypass the rate limit?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [twitter api max app per developer account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910982/twitter-api-max-app-per-developer-account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deliberately creating multiples for the purpose of bypassing the rate limit is against the Twitter API Terms of Service and will get your applications banned.

If you need more data than the REST API rate limits allow, then you may need to use the Streaming API.

The rate limits exist to ensure the best quality of service for as many people as possible.  Don't abuse them.

Comment: But what is the answer to the question though? `how many apps can I build with one twitter account?`